# $.ajax is loading a different url from what I asked it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax is posting a wrong url each time I make a request using absolute url. For example, when I request for "http://localhost/app/home/session", it calls "http://localhost/app/home/home/session"

```
var baseUrl = function(link) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/app/';
    if( link ) {
        url += link;
    }
}

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: baseUrl('home/session'),
    data: {}
}).done(function () {
    //window.location = baseUrl('dashboard');
});
```

[image: Request Log]

Comment: Have you tried adding `return (url);` to the end of your `baseUrl()` function? As it is, your function returns nothing :)

Comment: The `url` property in the config object is `undefined`

Comment: function doesn't return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not returning anything

please use the following:

```
var baseUrl = function(link) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/app/';
    if( link ) {
        url += link;
    }

return url;
}
```

Comment: You're right.. I just figured that out.
How could I miss that?

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
function baseUrl(link) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/app/';
    if( link ) {
        url += link;
    }
    return url;
}

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: baseUrl('home/session'),
    data: {}
}).done(function () {
    //window.location = baseUrl('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your baseUrl is missing a return statement